# PHP and MySQL mysqli->prepare keeps failing in FPDF file

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ok. I'm trying to prevent SQL injections on my first project build with FPDF.

(Since my insecure solution is working I suspect it has nothing in particular to do with FPDF. Just thought I'd mention that this is used to get data for generating a PDF :) )

The code below is working mighty fine. But it vulnerable to injections:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('','','',''); // Empty on purpose due to posting here :)

$IDQuery = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT ID FROM sendsubmits WHERE ID = $ID");
```

The `$ID` is an integer taken from the url like this:

```
$ID = htmlspecialchars($_GET["ID"]);
```

As far as I understand I need to swap `$ID` with `?`. And then use bind_param to have it inserted.

I've tried and follow the doc here:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

And my result is this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('','','',''); // Empty on purpose due to posting here :)

/* Check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


$IDQuery = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT ID FROM sendsubmits WHERE ID = ?');
$IDQuery = bind_param('i', $ID);
$IDQuery = execute();

printf('%d Row inserted.\n', $stmt->affected_rows);

$IDQuery->close();
```

This isn't working. And I can't seem to figure out why.

Any suggestions?

Comment: First, you keep reassigning `$IDQuery`, second, `bind_param` and `execute` aren't functions, they're methods on the statement object? Is this your actual code as I'd expect this to fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

Not `$IDQuery = bind_param('i', $ID);`

but `$IDQuery->bind_param('i', $ID);`

The same with execute. Next time try to understand what you read in manual